# Docker container not saved

Tags: tomcat, docker

Just started with Docker and stuck with an issue.
I'm running tomcat inside docker container. Docker image name = `tomcat7.0.79`
Started the container using the command:
`docker run -it --net=host tomcat7.0.79 /bin/bash`

Installed vi editor using `apt-get update && apt-get install vi`
Then updated users in tomcat-users.xml, exited the prompt and committed the docker container. Next time when I run the same container using the command `docker run -it --net=host tomcat7.0.79 /bin/bash`, the vi package is now missing. Why is it missing even after I committed the container? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `docker run` command always launch a new container. If you want to re-run your committed changes, you have to run the new image you committed.

For example,

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED      STATUS              PORTS              NAMES
c3f279d17e0a        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago   Up 25 hours                            desperate_dubinsky

$ docker commit c3f279d17e0a  nishant/testimage:v1
f5283438590d

$ docker run -d nishant/testimage:v1
```

Comment: Thank you @ivan.sim +1. It helped.